# Donut.cvs example

Tags: cygwin, action, mahout, donut-chart

I can't find a way to config mahout correctly. That's what happens when I try to run the "donut.cvs" example from "Mahout in Action" book:

```
Running on hadoop, using /home/myname/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /home/myname/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
Not a valid JAR: C:\home\myname\mahout\mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
```

where do I have to change parameters?

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from Hadoop binary and not from mahout. The source file is RunJar.java where it is trying to validate the existence of mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar and failed. Assuming tghat you are running it from Cygwin, issue here is that you are getting an unwanted `C:/home` (as opposed to `/home`) at the trailing end of the JAR file path.